# Target unkown after Android 4.3 update

Tags: android, eclipse, galaxy, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I updated my Samsung Galaxy S3 from 4.1.2 to 4.3 and eclipse shows my target device as unknown (with the orange triangle). Querying for adb devices from command prompt shows my device name but has its state as 'unauthorized'. I have updated the sdk to the latest, toggled USB debugging on my device, restarted eclipse, tried to use adb to kill-server and start-server but none of these approaches seems to solve my problem. One peculiar behavior is that on toggling debugging and reconnecting to my pc, I do not get a RSA key fingerprint popup requesting for permission.

I would appreciate any help on this matter.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: I just wanted to add that I tried both MTP and PTP mode

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable the developer options again after updating:
[Enable Hidden Dev Options](http://gs4.wonderhowto.com/how-to/enable-hidden-developer-options-your-samsung-galaxy-s4-0146687/)

Comment: Hello, I already have developer options and USB debugging enabled :(

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem with my galaxy S4.
After many hours of research and trying all of what you suggested and even factory resetting - I discovered that it is some bug / issue with Samsung devices running 4.3

I had 4.2.2 running fine, upgraded to 4.3 and like you say - phone became unrecognized, Logcat did not show anything.

At last, I downgraded back to 4.2.2 and everything was back to normal.
Take note that it happens for no obvious reason, and only on some devices - not all.

So, unfortunately, the only probable solution is to revert back to your old Android version and then it should work fine.

Cheers..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to roll back to 4.2.2 without rooting my phone? What is weird is that the phone is being recognized fine on other windows machines with the same OS. I'm able to force other machines to use the google USB driver, but this one absolutely refuses to load the .inf file. I tried removing Samsung kies and Samsung USB drivers in case there was a conflict, but the issue still remains.

Comment: Just for interest sake, try downloading an app called "Catlog" (an app that acts as the Logcat in Eclipse) and see if you are able to get continous Logcat readings from your device.

Comment: Hey, I downloaded catlog and I'm getting continous prints [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2s8cwnR03B8NkVIZ1ZlMU8wbUE/edit?usp=sharing) irrespective of if I'm connected to my pc or not. It also complains about my device not being rooted.

Comment: Well, if the Catlog shows continious information about your device - you are still better off then what I had.
Try this - Make sure the phone is NOT connected to the computer, in the Dev options on your phone, somewhere by the Enable Debugging - look for an option that says "Revoke" something (it clears all computers you have authorized for USB debugging). Then try to reconnect to computer, authorize it and see if it has helped...

Comment: That didn't work either :( Another weird observation. My iphone also comes up as "usb device not recognized " and installing its drivers doesn't seem to work either. Only a Galaxy S3 with 4.1.2 gets detected. I'm starting to wonder if some weird windows update has messed up USB drivers.

Comment: I read somewhere else that the USB cable that comes with a Samsung phone is proprietary and that 4.3 takes advantage of this.  If you are not using the cable that came with the phone then it may be that this is the issue (and why for some people it works fine).  Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure out which of the 30 usb cables I have is the Samsung one so I can't confirm or otherwise, but it might be worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the phone shows up in the eclipse but under unintelligible name and cannot be used. Switching to MTP and then back to PTP on the phone under USB options helps.

Answer (score 0):

download and install samsung kies 3
in kies 3, select tools-> setup driver again

this solved my problem